# Is there a better method for configuring DNS resolution in Spring reactor netty code?

Tags: dns, reactor-netty

My goal is to set up a specific DNS resolution configuration for a reactor netty HTTPClient (io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.0.7) being used in a Kotlin application, and came up with the following:

```
    private val nioEventLoopGroup = NioEventLoopGroup()
    private val httpClient = HttpClient
        .create()
        .resolver(
            DnsAddressResolverGroup(
                DnsNameResolverBuilder(nioEventLoopGroup.next())
                    .channelType(NioDatagramChannel::class.java)
                    .nameServerProvider(
                        SequentialDnsServerAddressStreamProvider(
                            InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.53", 53),
                            InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.63", 53)))))
```

First, that seems fairly complex for what seems like the simple task of identifying the DSN server IP address used for DNS resolution.  I was wondering if there's a better method of configuration using a Customizer class or Spring properties.  I haven't found anything yet in my reading, but I'm inexperienced in the ways of Spring IOC.

Secondly, configuring DNS resolver IP addresses shouldn't involve the threading strategy used by the internal Spring reactor DNS resolvers, so the requirement of my technique to create a new thread pool, and picking the first one off the top to use for all the DNS resolutions seems problematic at best, which is why I think I'm missing the boat on how DNS resolver IP address configuration should be done properly.

Is there a more appropriate way to configure DNS resolver IP addresses within a reactor netty HTTPClient?

Comment: May be check this https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_host_name_resolution_2

Comment: Wow.  I think I may have just lost my website navigation credentials!  Not sure how I missed your documentation source in my Googling, but thanks for the pointer.  It may address my first concern if I spent more time studying it, but it definitely led me to a better approach to the second concern, which had more significance than the form the configuration took.  I'll post my solution below.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation identified above (https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_host_name_resolution_2), this configuration:

> | Configuration name | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | runOn | Performs the communication with the DNS servers on the given LoopResources. By default, the LoopResources specified on the client level are used. |

indicates that the thread pool (EventLoopGroup) should be specified on the HttpClient for use by internal components used by the HttpClient, such as the DNS Resolver.  This implies the following implementation, which makes much more sense to me.  Please comment if you think otherwise.

```
    private val httpClient = HttpClient
        .create().runOn(NioEventLoopGroup())
        .resolver(
            DnsAddressResolverGroup(
                DnsNameResolverBuilder()
                    .channelType(NioDatagramChannel::class.java)
                    .nameServerProvider(
                        SequentialDnsServerAddressStreamProvider(
                            InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.54", 53),
                            InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.64", 53)))))
```

Comment: FYI, the above post looks much better in the preview in which the quoted text is a table with headers and row values.  I'm not sure why the preview would show a deceptive rendering of the post, but maybe table markup is not honored within a block quote in the post renderer but is in the preview renderer?  Seems weird to me.  Is it worth filing a bug?

Comment: Do you need always to run with NIO or you may run also with native transport. By default you do not need to specify the `runOn`, if you are OK with the default implementation. Also you are still using your way of building the resolver, look at the examples how I can be built without `DnsNameResolverBuilder`.